# Seperate time intervals by workday

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table (but with much more data):

`Workcenter ID  |   Status  |    Start Date/Time  |   End Date/Time
SLX83D          Breakdown     11/27/2016 16:00:00    11/29/2016 12:30:00
SLX83C          No Operator   11/27/2016 6:40:00     11/27/2016 13:00:00
SLX83A          QA Inspection 11/28/2016 13:00:00    11/28/2016 14:00:00 
SLX83A          QA Inspection 11/28/2016 15:00:00    11/28/2016 16:00:00`

I would like to separate the status time intervals by workday (ie 12/1 6am to 12/2 6am) and sum.

My idea was to create a crosstab query in the following format:

`Work Day   | Workcenter ID | Breakdown | No Operator | QA Inspection
11/27/2016   SLX83D           14:00:00
11/28/2016   SLX83D           24:00:00
11/29/2016   SLX83D            6:30:00
11/27/2016   SLX83C                        6:20:00
11/28/2016   SLX83A                                      2:00:00`

Couldn't figure how to make it work, I'm open to other ideas.

P.S. 
I also have the following columns in my table: Start date, Start time, End Date, and End time. (these were used to calculate 'start date/time' and 'end date/time'

I'm relatively new to Access and know next to nothing about SQL, thanks.

Edit: 
I was able to find the status for a given day by creating the following calculated columns in my table:

Is between Date: 
`IIf([Start Date/Time]>= "11/28/2016 06:00:00" And [End Date/Time]<= "11/29/2016 06:00:00" ,[End Date/Time]-[Start Date/Time],0)*24*60`

Starts Before Date: 
`IIf([Start Date/Time]< "11/28/2016 06:00:00" And [End Date/Time]>= "11/28/2016 06:00:00" And [End Date/Time]<= "11/29/2016 06:00:00" ,[End Date/Time]- "11/28/2016 06:00:00" ,0)*24*60`

Ends After Date: 
`IIf([End Date/Time]> "11/28/2016 06:00:00" And [Start Date/Time]>= "11/28/2016 06:00:00" And [Start Date/Time]<= "11/29/2016 06:00:00" , "11/29/2016 06:00:00" -[Start Date/Time],0)*24*60`

Spans Whole Date: 
`IIf([Start Date/Time]< "11/28/2016 06:00:00" And [End Date/Time]> "11/29/2016 06:00:00" ,1,0)*24*60`

Summing these columns gives the total number of minutes a given workcenter had a given status on a given day.
However, this only works for one workday date at a time.  I would much rather figure out how use SQL to get the results like the table above for a history of workdays.

`Workcenter ID |   Status  |  Start Date/Time   |  End Date/Time
SLX83D         Breakdown     11/27/2016 16:00:00  11/29/2016 12:30:00
SLX83A         QA Inspection 11/28/2016 13:00:00  11/28/2016 14:00:00 
SLX83A         QA Inspection 11/28/2016 15:00:00  11/28/2016 16:00:00`

`Workcenter ID | IBD | SBD | EAD | SWD | SUM
SLX83D                            1440  1440 (24 hrs)
SLX83A           60                      60  (1 hr)
SLX83A           60                      60  (These 2 hrs would have to be summed later somehow, this isn't a great solution)`

Edit 2:
I tried the following but can't get it to work. (credit goes to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cca28ddd-2041-4504-b602-3bedd9ca704e/counts-by-time-interval?forum=transactsql#208e97ad-11a7-4d96-9436-c82612755d46)

```
SELECT DatePart(Day,[Start Date/Time]) AS [Workday Date], Count([Status Table].[Workcenter ID]) AS [Workday Interval]

FROM [Status Table]

WHERE ((([Status Table].[Start Date/Time]) Between [Start Date/Time] And [End Date/Time]))

GROUP BY DatePart(Day,interval);
```

Comment: What is desired result with your example data?

Comment: @Parfait, I would like to know the total amount of time a workcenter was in given status on a given workday (ie SLX83D had a status that spanned 3 workdays and would be split up.  SLX83A had the same status twice in a workday so they are added together).  Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider handling your needs in multiple stages:

1. Build a *Schedule* table of all possible workdays start (first day 6:00 AM) and end points (next day 5:59 AM). This may require using VBA loop to dynamically create a new table ([TableDef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195790.aspx)) from earliest to latest date in range if days are into the hundreds or thousands.

   [image: Schedule Table]
2. Union query combining all three possible durations: a) partial day start; b) multiple full day(s); c) partial day end. Each using nested `IIF()` logic to calculate hours. Each `SELECT` query will run a cross join and interval filter with *Actual Hours* table and above *Schedule* table.
3. Cross tab query to aggregate in transformed output grouped by *WorkDates* and *ID*, pivoted by *Status* columns.

**Union Query** *(be sure to remove comments, not compliant in Access SQL query statement).*

```
-- ACTUAL START PARTIAL
SELECT w.[Workcenter ID], w.Status, w.[StartDate/Time], w.[End Date/Time], 
       s.WorkStartDates, s.WorkEndDates,
       IIF(w.[StartDate/Time] >= s.WorkStartDates AND w.[End Date/Time] <= s.WorkEndDates,
         DateDiff('n', w.[StartDate/Time], w.[End Date/Time]), 
         IIF(w.[StartDate/Time] >= s.WorkStartDates AND w.[End Date/Time] >= s.WorkEndDates,
             DateDiff('n', w.[StartDate/Time], s.WorkEndDates), NULL)) / 60 AS WorkHours
FROM WorkCenterHours w, Schedule s
WHERE w.[StartDate/Time] BETWEEN s.WorkStartDates AND s.WorkEndDates

UNION

-- ACTUAL START AND END ACROSS WORKDAYS
SELECT w.[Workcenter ID], w.Status, w.[StartDate/Time], w.[End Date/Time], 
       s.WorkStartDates, s.WorkEndDates,
       DateDiff('n', s.WorkStartDates, s.WorkEndDates) / 60 As WorkHours
FROM WorkCenterHours w, Schedule s
WHERE s.WorkStartDates BETWEEN w.[StartDate/Time] AND w.[End Date/Time]
AND s.WorkEndDates BETWEEN w.[StartDate/Time] AND w.[End Date/Time]

UNION 

-- ACTUAL END LEFTOVER
SELECT w.[Workcenter ID], w.Status, w.[StartDate/Time], w.[End Date/Time],
       s.WorkStartDates, s.WorkEndDates,
       IIF(w.[StartDate/Time] <= s.WorkStartDates AND w.[End Date/Time] <= s.WorkEndDates,
         DateDiff('n', w.[End Date/Time], s.WorkEndDates), 
         IIF(w.[StartDate/Time] >= s.WorkStartDates AND w.[End Date/Time] <= s.WorkEndDates,
             DateDiff('n', w.[StartDate/Time], w.[End Date/Time]), NULL)) / 60 AS WorkHours
FROM WorkCenterHours w, Schedule s
WHERE w.[End Date/Time] BETWEEN s.WorkStartDates AND s.WorkEndDates;
```

[image: Union Query]

**Cross Tab Query** *(uses above as data source)*

```
TRANSFORM Sum(q.WorkHours) AS SumOfWorkHours
SELECT DateValue(q.WorkStartDates) AS WorkDate, q.[Workcenter ID]
FROM UnionSourceQuery q
GROUP BY DateValue(q.WorkStartDates), q.[Workcenter ID]
PIVOT q.Status;
```

[image: Cross Tab]

*NOTE: performance is not guaranteed and may vary with size of data with this solution due to the cross join filters inside a union query using nested logic and various date function calls and ultimately is then pivoted.*

Comment: I just changed the 5th from the last line on union query to:`DateDiff('n', s.WorkStartDates, w.[End Date/Time] ), ` Does that seem right? I think it's working perfectly now.

Comment: Good catch! Indeed it should be changed to that! Just making sure you are paying attention =) ...Glad I could help.

Comment: Awesome, great solution! Getting motivating to learn SQL now :)